# Upper case letters first when sorting with localeCompare()

Tags: javascript

I want to sort an array with strings alphabetically. However, upper case letters should be always before the corresponding lower case letter (example order: A a B b ...).

To archive this, I have tried to use `localCompare` with `caseFirst: "upper"` and `sensitivity: "case"`:

```js
const input = ["ADR 2023", "Added Values", "DEMO build", "DEMO Build", "2nd Outlook", "demo award"]
const output = input.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "en-US", { caseFirst: "upper", sensitivity: "case" }))
console.log(output)
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
["2nd Outlook", "ADR 2023", "Added Values", "DEMO Build", "DEMO build", "demo award"]
```

Unfortunately, the output is:

```
["2nd Outlook", "Added Values", "ADR 2023", "demo award", "DEMO Build", "DEMO build"]
```

How can I get the expected order? In the example, I have used `en-US` as locale. However, in my real project, it can be any supported locale with a length of five characters.

Comment: « In implementations without Intl.Collator support, this parameter is ignored.« see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: You can’t use caseFirst without Intl.Collator.

Comment: You should « create an Intl.Collator object and use the function provided by its compare() method.«

Comment: I use Chrome 120. According to https://caniuse.com/?search=intl.collator, Intl.Collator should be supported.

Comment: Good news. So implement it and you are good to go!

Comment: @Klaassiek "*create an Intl.Collator object and use the function provided by its compare() method*" doesn't seem to work https://jsbin.com/xufowamira/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Unfortunately, Intl.Collator("en-US", { caseFirst: "upper", sensitivity: "case" }).compare() does give me the expected order either.

Comment: I think caseFirst just means  `Aa` & `aA` , IOW  `a === A`, but `A < a`.. All other sort logic stays the same.   aka.  `0 < 1` etc..  eg. Try changing caseFirst to lower to see the difference.

Comment: Just wondering how you want to order `A10` and `A9`

Comment: @Wyck not relevant for this question but that'd be a case for `numeric: true`. This question focuses on the case sorting.

Comment: Could you be more explicit on your requirements, is it always  Alpha,Number etc.

Comment: @Keith In my real project, the text to sort are headlines with real words. The locale depends on the language of the words. There are about 40 supported languages. However, I compare only headline within the same language.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show some more example data, that's more like what your wanting to sort.   Also again show expected output.  You might be able to do what your after with a simple custom sort, mixed with some regEx, and some more realistic example data will help here..

Comment: @Keith Seems pretty clear to me: all uppercase variants first, then the lowercase variants. "Aardvark" and "Aaron" and  before "aardvark" and "aaron". Same as how using relational operators with strings (`a < b` /`a > b`) would work for English (for the same base letters, at least). But should work for languages other than English.

Comment: @VLAZ  I can easy make the sort work with the current example data, but to be 100% sure it would be nice for the OP to supply some realistic data.  eg.. what would happen with `AAron` & `Aron`,  is it only the first letter etc.  Seen as it's titles what about full caps,  it's headline data after all.

Comment: @Keith I have updated my question by using more realistic example data. The number of words does vary in reality. However, I have limited the headlines to two words in my question to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `localeCompare()` since it creates `Intl.Collator` every time - tooooo slow.
2. You can compare char by char ensuring that any number of upper case letters could be processed.

```js
const input = ["ADR 2023", "Added Values", "DEMO build", "DEMO Build", "2nd Outlook", "demo award"];
const {compare} = Intl.Collator("en-US", { caseFirst: "upper"});
const output = input.sort((a, b) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++){
    const r = compare(a[i], b[i]);
    if(r) return r;
  }
  if(a.length > b.length) return 1;
  if(a.length < b.length) return -1;
  return 0;
})
console.log(output)
```

A string iterator version as suggested by VLAZ:

```js
const input = ["ADR 2023", "Added Values", "DEMO build", "DEMO Build", "2nd Outlook", "demo award"];
const {compare} = Intl.Collator("en-US", { caseFirst: "upper"});
const output = input.sort((a, b) => {
  const ia = a[Symbol.iterator](), ib = b[Symbol.iterator]();
  while(true){
    const ca = ia.next().value, cb = ib.next().value;
    if(!ca) return ba ? -1 : 0
    if(ca && !cb) return 1;
    const r = compare(ca, cb);
    if(r) return r;
  }
})
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It does exactly what I want to achieve and even works with my real headlines.

Comment: Rather than indexing the strings, use the iterators they expose. That is safer with multibyte characters. `itA = a[Symbo.iterator](); itB = B[Symbo.iterator]();` then take `itA.next()` and `itB.next()` until one returns a `done: true`

Comment: @Martin added a string iterator version